# Unpivot - Ignore if value is null

Tags: google-sheets, null, pivot, unpivot, isnull

in Google Sheet, I use this formula to unpivot a table:

=arrayformula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/";"Foglio1!A2:A999")&"|"&IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/";"Foglio1!AQ1:BB1")&"|"&IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/";"Foglio1!AQ2:BB999"));"|"))

The data structure is like in the screenshot: the problem is that the unpivoting create row also when (for example) Alpha in Project A is null.

How can i fix this problem, creating unpivoted rows only if the value in the cell is > 0?

Many thanks mate!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgZqX.png)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please show a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of a reasonable amont of realistic-looking sample data together with a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the formula in a `query()`, like this:

```
=query( arrayformula(...); "where Col3 is not null"; 1 )
```

Comment: I have tried but if give me error in formula: are you sure that i can use an arrayformula inside a Query?

Comment: In the event your spreadsheet locale uses commas `,` as decimal separators, you will have to use semicolons `;` as formula argument separators. Edited the answer.